# Elegir entre formato "compressed" vs "dynamic" InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

Estoy intentando determinar cuál es el formato de registro óptimo para la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE `USUARIO_TURISTA` (
  `Login` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(320) NOT NULL,
  `Telefono` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Direccion` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Fecha_Nacimiento` date NOT NULL,
  `Numero_Tarjeta` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Tipo_Tarjeta` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Fecha_Caducidad` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Login`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
```

He ido variando el formato de registro, para ver cómo varía también su tamaño.  Dadas las características de los datos a almacenar en la tabla, hay varios atributos cuyas longitudes máximas y mínimas varían mucho, como por ejemplo, "Nombre", "Direccion"... Por ello he llegado a la conclusión que los que menos ocupan son los registros con formatos "compressed" y "dynamic", confirmándolo viendo que el tamaño en bytes de la tabla es significativamente menor con estos formatos que con los demás ("redundant" y "compact").

Mi duda es, ¿cómo elegir entre el formato "dynamic" y "compressed"?

Mirando en la documentación de Mysql he visto que "compressed" proporciona las mismas características que el dinámico, añadiendo sólo una compresión al registro, lo cual incrementará el uso de CPU del SGBD.

[innodb-row-format-compressed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format.html#innodb-row-format-compressed)

No sé por tanto, qué tiene mayor peso en la elección. Si es el tamaño que ocupan con los dos formatos, que con "compressed" es un 10% menor frente da "dynamic"; o si, por el contrario pesa más el uso adicional de CPU que implicaría el formato "compressed".

Ahora dispongo de los datos que os puede ayudar a tomar una decisión: El número de registros que tengo en esta tabla es de 9000. Las transacciones que manipulan los registros son tanto de lectura, como de escritura, con un nivel de aislamiento "repeatable read". El servidor donde se almacena los datos tiene una memoria de 4GB y dos CPU de 2GHz.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es fácil de responder porque faltan datos y aún así, no te quedará otro camino que hacer evaluaciones si fuera necesario. Cosas esenciales que no has dicho: ¿hay muchas tablas con campos grandes, tipo BLOB o TEXT u otras? ¿necesitas índices para esos campos? ¿la BD será consultada de forma remota? ¿por qué media de usuarios? ¿es una BD que tiene tendencia a crecer con el tiempo? ¿en tu entorno qué es más importante el ancho de banda, el consumo de CPU, el uso de espacio de almacenamiento? ¿hay límites en esas áreas? ... y así, hay muchas interrogantes más para poder decidir...

Comment: ...incluso hay una pregunta que tendrías que hacerte: ¿necesitas realmente compresión de datos para esta tabla? ¿por qué?